# Convert PIL image to bytearray

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In C#, I can use `Bitmap.lockbits()` to access a bitmap as a byte array. How to do this in PIL? I have tried `Image.write()` but it wrote a full format image to a stream.

Comment: Maybe `Image.tobytes()`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann, see the warning in the [```tobytes```](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes) method.

Comment: @wwii What about it?

Comment: @StefanPochmann tobytes() returns the raw image. For compressed formats you should use save() as proposed by the answer given

Answer (score 20):

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

with BytesIO() as output:
    with Image.open(path_to_image) as img:
        img.save(output, 'BMP')
    data = output.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 9):

> .. warning::
>
> This method returns the raw image data from the internal
>      storage.  For compressed image data (e.g. PNG, JPEG) use
>      :meth:`~.save`, with a BytesIO parameter for in-memory
>      data.

This is the warning in the *tobytes* method. So we can use the *save* method with a BytesIO parameter to get a compressed byte array.

```
import io

byteIO = io.BytesIO()
image.save(byteIO, format='PNG')
byteArr = byteIO.getvalue()
```

Comment: Thanks for this super clear explanation. This code works very well!

Comment: What exactly is `image` referencing?